# Pole of two variable function

Tags: complex-analysis

Define the two variable function $H(z,\tau)$ on $\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}$ as follows

$H(z,\tau):=\frac{p}{q-p}+\sum\limits_{m\in I}p^{-m}q^m-\sum\limits_{n\in J}p^nq^{-n}+\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j}a(i,j)p^iq^j$, where $p=e^{2\pi i\tau}$ and $q=e^{2\pi iz}$

$I,J$ are some finite index sets and assume that double series converges absolutely for all $p,q$ with $|p|,|q|<1$

Then author proved that $H(z,\tau)$ has a pole at all points $(z,\tau)$ where $z=\gamma\tau$ for some $\gamma\in\Gamma$

Here, $\Gamma$ is a finite index subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ which consists of all 2 by 2 integer matrix with determinant 1 and $\gamma\tau$ is defined via mobius transformation.

I did not explain the several settings in detail but just focus on the definition of $H(z,\tau)$

My question is that $H(z,\tau)$ can have a pole at the point $(z,\tau)$ with $q\neq p$???

Given $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$, we can check that there exists $\gamma\in\Gamma$ such that $e^{2\pi i\gamma\tau}\neq e^{2\pi i\tau}$

So if $H(z,\tau)$ cannot have a pole at the point $(z,\tau)$ with $q\neq p$, then theorem does not hold.

Hence we conclude that $H(z,\tau)$ can have a pole at the point $(z,\tau)$ with $q\neq p$ but I don't know why.(we assume that second and third sum are finite sum and that double series converges absolutely)

Did I misunderstood some basic concepts??